# Mac OS "Go to desktop #" keyboard shortcourt

Tags: macos, desktop

I am looking for a shortcut to change desktop in Mac OS X (10.7.3)

I am used to awesome WM in which you can do + to go to desktop #

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut in MacOS X to do this. I tried to make one using jiTouch but I didn't succeed.

Note: I am not asking to show/display the current desktop, only moving between them directly by their ID.

I have 5 desktop and going from #1 to #5 can take some time especially with the sliding effects. this is a productivity killer.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, you can use ^N, where N is the number of the desktop, to move between desktops.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't saw this in the configuration. Works ok.